# finite or infinite complex sets

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

In my view all the sets must be infinite as there will be different values of complex numbers for different values of n.However I am not sure about it.please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: $A_1$ will have exactly two elements : $e^in\pi=(-1)^n$.

Comment: Recall that $e^{i\theta}$ represents points on the unit circle in the complex plane for various $\theta$. Not all sets are infinite. Here's a counter example: Let $r=1$, then consider different values of n, and the corresponding values of $e^{i\pi r n}$. Are they all distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example to get you started:
$$A_1=\{e^{i\pi n}\ \mid\ n\ \hbox{is a natural number}\}\ .$$
Now $n$ is either even or odd.  If it's even then $e^{i\pi n}=1$; if it's odd then $e^{i\pi n}=-1$.  Therefore
$$A_1=\{1,-1\}$$
which is not an infinite set.

I think you should be able to do the rest from here.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,following your answer the correct option should be D).As $0.3n\pi$ will repeat itself after certain values of n.it was of great help.thanks.